# Assertion failure in -[UITableView _classicHeightForRowAtIndexPath:],

Tags: ios, uitableview

hideCellConst variable calculate the hide all views height and returns the height of tableview cell.but it given above error.

This custom cell created. i want to calculate all hide views height constant value and return the height of cell based on show view constant

```
class View_Partner_Pref_Cell:UITableViewCell{



 @IBOutlet var viewHeightImage: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var viewHeightHideAll: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var lblDetails1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblDetails2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblDetails3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblDetails4: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var view3: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var viewHeight1: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var viewHeight2: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var viewHeight3: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var viewHeight4: NSLayoutConstraint!
  }





 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 8{

                        return 455 - hideCellConst
                    }

        }
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    if indexPath.section == 8 {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("partnerPrefCell") as! View_Partner_Pref_Cell

                    let pModel = partnerPrefArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PartnerPreferencesModel
      if pModel.age == ""{
                        cell.view1.hidden = true
                        hideCellConst += cell.viewHeight1.constant
                        cell.viewHeight1.constant = 0
                    }else{
                        cell.view1.hidden = false
                        cell.viewHeight1.constant = 25
                        cell.lblDetails1.text = "Age: \(pModel.age)"
                    }
                    if pModel.height == ""{
                        cell.view2.hidden = true
                        hideCellConst += cell.viewHeight2.constant
                        cell.viewHeight2.constant = 0
                    }else{
                        cell.view2.hidden = false
                        cell.viewHeight2.constant = 25
                        cell.lblDetails2.text = "Height: \(pModel.height)"
                    }
                    if pModel.body_type == ""{
                        cell.view3.hidden = true
                         hideCellConst += cell.viewHeight3.constant
                        cell.viewHeight3.constant = 0
                    }else{
                        cell.view3.hidden = false
                        cell.viewHeight3.constant = 25
                        cell.lblDetails3.text = "Body Type: \(pModel.body_type)"
                    }
                    if pModel.marital_status == ""{
                        cell.view4.hidden = true
                         hideCellConst += cell.viewHeight4.constant
                        cell.viewHeight4.constant = 0
                    }else{
                        cell.view4.hidden = false
                        cell.viewHeight4.constant = 25
                        cell.lblDetails4.text = "Marital Status: \(pModel.marital_status)"
                    }
             return cell
    }
     return cell
    }
```

Comment: you seem to be missing a return statement? is this the actual code or is some omitted

Comment: i already return statement defined in my code but i return static value its works but above calculate varialbe code not work properly

Comment: Might be your hide is -negative, please show your code in detail?

Comment: First thing to note is that the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath :` will return a value only for the rows of ninth section of the tableView i.e. `indexPath.section == 8`. And what is this `hideCellConst `?

Comment: ideCellConst variable calculate the hide all views constant height which returns as uitableview cell height

Comment: This problem you can try to check whether caused by cellHight height less than 0

Answer (score 0):

@user7301096 comment is the correct solution. Your logic might be correct however if the calculated rowHeight is less than 0 you'll get this exception. Simple fix here is to return zero in the event it is less than.